# Access to controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action

I have Controller with some method GET :

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
   public List<T> Get(){...}

   [ActionName("GetById")]
   public T Get(int id){...}
}
```

Can i access second Get method as `/Get?id=1` even if i have different ActionName?

> ActionName for generating cache with different names

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @RoyDictus, i tried it with no success, so i thought maybe some changes in WebApiConfig will help

Answer (score 0):

Updated because my previous answer was related to standard MVC controllers not Web API because that is what the `ActionName` attribute is for.  I am not sure what if anything it would do on a web api controller. Without attributes or a change from the deault routing your actions would have the following routes `"/api/test/" Get()` `"/api/test/id" Get(int id)` where id is an int.

If you want more flexibility MVC5 supports [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)